# How to get format output of Multi-Dim Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array, `$cat_group_array`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0010
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - STRIPLOINS
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0015
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - RIBEYES
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0020
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - T-BONE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0025
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - TENDERLOIN
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0030
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - TOP SIRLOIN
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 01
            [pgroup] => 0035
            [pgroup_name] => STEAKS - Other Varieties
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 05
            [pgroup] => 0145
            [pgroup_name] => CHICKEN - Ground
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 05
            [pgroup] => 0150
            [pgroup_name] => CHICKEN-BREADED
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 05
            [pgroup] => 0155
            [pgroup_name] => CHICKEN BREASTS (Raw Products)
        )
)
```

My goal is to get an output something like this where I display the groups and group names uner the Category Heading

```
Cat: 01

0010 - Steaks - Striploin
0015 - Steaks - Ribeyes
0020 - Steaks - T-Bone
0030 - Steaks - Top Sirloin
0035 - Steaks - Other Varieties

Cat: 05

0145 - Chicken Ground
0150 - Chicken Breaded
0155 - Chicken Breasts
```

I have tried several things, nothing has yeilded fruit yet. I have been trying something like this but I don't get output.

```
foreach ($cat_group_array as $key => $row) {     
    $test = $cat_group_array[$key]['cat'];
    echo "Category: " . $test;
    while ($cat_group_array[$key]['cat'] == $test) {
        echo "Pgroup #: " . $cat_group_array[$key]['pgroup'] .
        " Group Name = " . $cat_group_array[$key]['pgroup_name'] . "<br /><br />";    
    }
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Which php version you run on?

Comment: I am running version 5.5.28 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in several ways. I will provide a solution where you don't need the original array to be sorted by category. It first creates another array keyed by category name, holding sub-arrays with the rows that belong to it. Then it iterates over these categories, and per category iterates over the rows:

```
foreach ($cat_group_array as $row) {
    $categories[$row["cat"]][] = $row;
}
foreach ($categories as $name => $groups ) {
    echo "\n<h3>Category: $name</h3>\n\n";
    foreach ($groups as $group ) {
        echo "<p>{$group['pgroup']} {$group['pgroup_name']}</p>\n";
    }
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/631909).

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to know the categories ahead of time you can just extract them from the array using [`array_map`](http://php.net/array-map).

```
$categories = array_map(function($cat) {
    return $cat['cat'];
}, $cat_group_array);
```

Since you only need to know about unique categories you can use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array-unique) to weed out any duplicate categories.

```
$categories = array_unique($categories);
```

Now you can use the `$categories` array as a filter to get the desired final result using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter).

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $items = array_filter(function($item) use($category) {
        return $item['cat'] === $category;
    }, $cat_group_array);

    echo "Cat: $category\n\n";

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo "$pgroup - $pgroup_name\n";
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

The final result should be as expected.

```
Cat: 01

0010 - Steaks - Striploin
0015 - Steaks - Ribeyes
0020 - Steaks - T-Bone
0030 - Steaks - Top Sirloin
0035 - Steaks - Other Varieties

Cat: 05

0145 - Chicken Ground
0150 - Chicken Breaded
0155 - Chicken Breasts
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will play with this tomorrow. I have tried the suggestions above from trincot and it worked, I will give your answer a go tomorrow and work on understanding it.